# How i can update UITabBarController Appearance in real time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uiappearance

I can't update UIBarTintColor by pressing a UIButton, it doesn't work. This is my hierarchy:

```
AppDelegate > HomeViewController (that holds my tabBarController) > ChildViewController
```

I wanna change UiTabbarController color in real-time by pressing a button inside the ChildViewController. This is the code i use:

```
UIColor* blu = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0/255 green: 161.0/255 blue: 223.0/255 alpha: 1];
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:blu];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:blu];
[[UISlider appearance] setTintColor:blu];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:blu];
```

It doesn't change the color of my tabbar in real-time, it changes the color only if i use it during the init of the tabbar. I have search and tried different solutions:

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
```

not working in my case

```
CALayer *layer2 =  self.tabBarController.view.layer;
[layer2 setNeedsDisplay];
[layer2 displayIfNeeded];
```

not working in my case

```
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate
```

not working in my case.

I have also tried to create a method in appDelegate to contains all this tryings, and i have to tried this method from ChildViewController, instead o calling directly the code. The results are the same.
How i can do to refresh the uitabbar and change the color by pressing a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
UIColor* blu = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0/255 green: 161.0/255 blue: 223.0/255 alpha: 1];

[self.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:blu];
```

Comment: it works but in this way: [self.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:blu];

Answer (score 0):

Once try it by putting it on main thread something like,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIColor* blu = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0/255 green: 161.0/255 blue: 223.0/255 alpha: 1];
    [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:blu];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:blu];
    [[UISlider appearance] setTintColor:blu];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:blu];
});
```

Comment: just tried, in childviewcontroller e appdelegate, not working